# When creating a conda env: "CondaEnvException: Pip failed" (Conflicting Python dependencies: "guesslang" and "tensorflow")

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

When I run `conda env create -f environment.yml` on ubuntu 20.04, a dependency conflict occurs and I get the following error: `CondaEnvException: Pip failed`. How do I solve it?

I tried to update my anaconda environment, but that didn't work.

Output:

```
Collecting guesslang~=2.0
  Downloading guesslang-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.5 MB)
  Downloading guesslang-2.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
  Downloading guesslang-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
  Downloading guesslang-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (13.0 MB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pydriller to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.

The conflict is caused by:
    guesslang 2.2.1 depends on tensorflow==2.5.0
    guesslang 2.2.0 depends on tensorflow==2.5.0
    guesslang 2.0.3 depends on tensorflow==2.5.0
    guesslang 2.0.1 depends on tensorflow==2.2.0
    guesslang 2.0.0 depends on tensorflow==2.2.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict


Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Cannot install -r /home/yang/Documents/CVE/CVEfixes/condaenv.ko814pto.requirements.txt (line 2) because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

Comment: The next step is to identify packages with problems. If you would like a more precise answer, then please include relevant sections of the YAML file. Better, make a trimmed down version of the YAML that is still sufficient to trigger the error, which, based on the error message, might just be the `guesslang` and the `tensorflow` specifications.